# Php Curl to Send XML Data By GET Params

Tags: php, curl, get

i am trying to send an url encoded xml fields with curl. Is there another way send data except in url? Because i tried this but is throwed "No URL set!" error.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://setmpos.ykb.com/PosnetWebService/XML');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST /PosnetWebService/XML HTTP/1.1
Host: setmpos.ykb.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)
Pragma: nocache
Accept-Language: tr
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: ".strlen($url)."

$url");

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
   $message = curl_error($ch);
}
```

Comment: i know this is not working but why?
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GETFIELDS,$GETFIELDS);

Comment: please point out why none of these helped solve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=post+curl+php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, you're setting up a POST, but doing it via the custom handlers, when CURL's perfectly capable of doing a POST on its own, which means you're not really using a GET query:

How about:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array_of_fields_to_post);
```

instead?

Comment: i must connect to page by get method like www.example.com/?url=blabla. is it possible with postfields?

Comment: But with your CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, you're forcing CURL to do a post, so it's NOT a get.